# Error when trying to clear react-native cache

Tags: react-native, npm

When doing `npm start -- --reset-cache` or `yarn start --reset-cache` I get the error `error: unknown option '--reset-cache'`

npm version 8.5.5
yarn version 1.22.17

Answer (score 1):

How about `npx react-native start --reset-cache` ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying `npm start -- -c` instead worked for me.